# JS DOM checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I have to enable/ disable a textarea based on whether the person clicks on a checkbox or not. I feel like I got the code right but for some reason it still isn't working. Am I calling the js file wrong in the script tag?
The javascript file name is task2.js.

Code in the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="task2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
  body { font-family: sans-serif;}
  .entry {
    background-color: silver;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px black solid;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .entry img {
    float:right;
    height: 200px;
    margin:10px;
    border: solid 1px black;
  }
  #container {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: LightSkyBlue;
    margins: auto;
    border: solid 5px black;
    font-size: 1.25em;
  }
  input[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  h1 { text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<h2> Order Information </h2>
<div class="entry">
  Select color:
  <select name="color">
    <option selected="selected">White</option>
    <option>Black</option>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  Select shirt size:
  <select name="sizeandprice">
    <option>Small - $9.99</option>
    <option>Medium - $10.99</option>
    <option selected="selected">Large - $11.99</option>
    <option>X-Large - $13.99</option>
  </select><br><br>
  Is this a gift? <input type="checkbox" name="gift" id="check"> <br><br>
  Write your gift message here: <br>
  <textarea disabled rows="5" cols="50" name="message" id="text">Type your message here.
  </textarea>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code in the javascript file:

```
document.getElementById("check").addEventListener('click', function(){
    var textArea = document.getElementById("text");
    textArea.disabled = !textArea.disabled;
});
```

Comment: Fixed the typo still isn't working, how do I call this js code on the console? Because I didn't give it a specific function name

Comment: Fixed it! I moved the script tag next to the closing body tag thanks everyone!